# Pytorch: Differentiable counting

Tags: pytorch, mathematical-optimization

I need to count the number of elements in a tensor that satisfy a condition, such as counting the number of people with age == 60, or people with age >= 50. Is there a differentiable approximation to the counting function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `torch.Tensor.sum` or [`torch.sum`](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/generated/torch.sum.html#torch.sum) on boolean tensor returned by `age >= 50`

```
age = torch.arange(75)

(age >= 50).sum()
tensor(25)
```