# A differentiable approach to counting elements in PyTorch

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, mathematical-optimization

I need to count the number of times a certain element appear in a tensor in a differentiable way.

I have a tensor

```
a = torch.arange(10, dtype = float, requires_grad=True)
print(a)
>>>tensor([0., 1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6., 7., 8., 9.], dtype=torch.float64,
       requires_grad=True)
```

Say I'm trying to count the number of times the element `5.0` appear. I found this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62783651/pytorch-differentiable-counting) question that is exactly the same, but the accepted answer is non differentiable:

```
(a == 5).sum()
>>>tensor(1)
(a == 5).sum().requires_grad
>>>False
```

My goal is to have a loss that enforces the element to appear `N` times:

```
loss = N - (a == 5).sum()
```

Comment: Maybe consider a different loss function? Like L1 loss?

Comment: Hmm interesting idea. I don't think that L1 would work quite well if I have a lot of values that are much larger than my element. However, that made me think of a potential approach. The idea is to subtract the `element` from the tensor. The output is differentiable and will be composed of potentially negatives, positives, and zeros. If there was a way to order and extract (e.g., a[:2]) the tensor of zeros that will be differentiable. Adding 1 to each element following by `sum` should give the actual count. Not sure how to extract the zeros though

Answer (score 0):

What you probably care about is differentiability wrt parameters, so your vector [1,2,3,4,5] is actually an output of f(x | theta). Sicne you casted everything onto integers, this will never create a meaningful gradient for theta, you have two paths:

1. Change your output, so that you do not output numbers, but rather distributions over number sequences, so instead of having a vector of integers, output a matrix of probabilities, N x K, where K is the maximum number and N number of integers, and an entry p_nk is a probability of nth number to be equal to k. Then, you can just write a nice smooth loss that will take expected number of each digit, lets call it Z (which is of length K) and then we can do

```
loss(P, Z) := - SUM_k [ || Z_k - [ SUM_n P_nk ] || ]
```

2. Treat the whole setup as RL problem, and then you do not need a "differentiable" loss. Just use a difference between expected occurences, and actual occurences as negative reward